# Рекомендуемый или общепринятый порядок обработки параметров в консольном приложении

Tags: архитектура, параметры

Надеюсь, это не флеймовый или оффтопик вопрос.
В консольном приложении (не важно, на чем написанном, для конкретики, пусть будет Java, но это не критично), существует возможность передавать параметры такими способами:

- значения параметров командной строки (-f value1)
- значения в файле конфигурации (xml, ini, yml, properties файлы и т.д.)
- значения переменных окружения ($F_PARAM_VALUE=value1)

Вопрос такой: в каком порядке приложение должно обрабатывать эти значения? Есть ли какие-то рекомендации, лучшие практики и т.д.?

Например, если значение указано и в файле конфигурации, и в параметрах переменных окружения, и в параметрах самого приложения, какое значение должно использоваться?

По логике вещей, самыми "сильными" должны быть параметры командной строки?

Comment: Я бы делал (по убыванию важности) командная строка, окружение, конфиг. Хотя конечно, что важнее конфиг или окружение это еще вопрос. Мне кажется могут быть разные ситуации.

Comment: Еще интересный кейс, когда есть параметр командной строки "путь к файлу конфига", и значение этого параметра - путь к несуществующему / неправильному файлу, а при этом есть валидные значения переменных окружения.

Comment: `путь к файлу конфига", и значение этого параметра - путь к несуществующему / неправильному файлу` просто ругаемся и завершаем работу приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Ну конечно в командной строке более приоритетные значения.
Их смысл в том, что можно запустить приложение в каком-то особом режиме,
отличном от настроек из конфига.
Если эти настройки не пересекаются, то вообще нет смысла определять приоритет.
Остальное дело техники. Можно параметры использовать для того, чтобы вызвать короткую функцию вообще без инициализации остальных настроек.